# Remove items from NSOrderedSet in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsorderedset

It try to remove items from `to-many` relationship like this:

```
(application.selectedDiagrams as! NSMutableOrderedSet).removeObjectsInRange(NSMakeRange(1, 2))
mainMOC.save(nil)
```

After I carry out commands, it seems to work, but latter deleted items appears again. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into a Swift versus Objective-C conflict. You are much better off using the standard Core Data add and remove objects methods. Hence, create an array with the objects you would like to remove and then pass it to `remove<Type>Objects:`.